# Increased count while finding matching recs using left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know this must be basic but to some bizarre reason I'm not getting my counts right when I left join my table. so basically tbl1 with 100 rows and tbl2 with 30recs. I'm trying to tbl1 with 2 to see how many records got their website address. But I'm getting a count much more than 100 which is my left most table. I even used distinct on tbl2 while joining but it's not helping.

tbl1

```
id, name, url, data1
```

tbl2

```
id,data3,data4,data5,data6,data6,website
```

tbl2 contains the  website data of records which are missing in tbl1, so I'm trying to map these to get the table right.

My query

```
select 
    t1.id, t1.name,
    coalesce(t1.url, t2.website) as url, t1.data1 
from 
    tbl1 
left join 
    (select disctinct id, website 
     from tbl2) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

I'm getting a total of 110 rows, ideally I should be getting just 100. Is any assumption possible here from experts to see why am I getting it or should I pour more data?

Thank you.

Comment: You must have some rows in t2 with duplicate Ids. `select Id from T2 group by Id having count(*)>1`

Comment: Are you sure your id is unique on your 2nd table?

Comment: @Dri372 no! that's why i using distinct.

Comment: You are not selecting `distinct` IDs only - you are selecting distinct Id *and* website - that's not the same thing

Comment: @Stu you're god damn right!! i was under impression that DISTINCT would nip out the dups. ( i know that i'm silly to miss this out ) thank you mate. If you could hook this comment up as an answer, i can approve it.

Comment: `Distinct` does exactly that - but two rows with the same Id but different websites are *both* distinct!

Comment: cqfd ...........

Answer (score 0):

Your `outer join` is matching multiple ID values.

To find the duplicate ID rows you can do

```
select *
from T2
where Id in (select Id from T2 group by Id having count(*)>1)
```

To get a 1:1 join in the example query you would need to `group` by the Id and also use an aggregate on the `website` column, or a `top (1)` clause if you have some other way of distinguishing, such as a `Createdate` column etc

eg

`left join (select Id, max(website) from tbl2 group by Id)`

Answer (score 0):

> tbl2 contains the website data of records which are missing in tbl1, so i'm trying to map these to get the table right.

Then we don't really care about records treat join multiple times because you're looking for records that join zero times:

```
select * 
from
  tbl1
  left join tbl2 on tbl1.id = tbl2.id
where
  tbl2.id is null
```

Or

```
select * 
from
  tbl1 x
where
  NOT EXISTS(select null from tbl2 y where x.id = y.id)
```

It will give you all the tbl1 rows that have no matching tbl2 row

If you want to use them to patch up tbl2 you can:

```
insert into tbl2(some,columns,here)
select columns,for,table2
from
  tbl1 x
where
  NOT EXISTS(select null from tbl2 y where x.id = y.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        t1.id
    ,   t1.name
    ,   url =   COALESCE(t1.url, t2.website)
    ,   t1.data1 
FROM        tbl1    T1 
LEFT JOIN   tbl2    T2  ON  T2.id = T1.id
```